# How to make programmatically a toolBar with next and previous on keyboard to navigate between editable fields?

Tags: iphone

How to make programmatically a toolBar with next and previous on keyboard to navigate between editable fields (Textfield, Textarea, Datepicker, Pikerview ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls

this control can show a toolbar above the keyboard when editing a textfield like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *prevButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Prev" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(prevButtonPressed:)];    
UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(nextButtonPressed:)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)]

UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
[toolbar setItems:@[prevButton, nextButton, flexibleSpace, doneButton]];

UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] inithWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
textView.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
```

You can use a `UISegmentedControl` to create the Prev/Next effect similar to the one posted by @adali